# Show Different Language Flags instead of Dropdown Magento

Tags: magento

the getskinurl() function is going in to base path to get images

```
<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
<div id="languages_box">
<ul id='languages'>
<?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
<?php $_selected = ($_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId()) ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrententer code hereUrl() ?>">
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/flags/'.$_lang->getCode().'.gif');?>" alt="<?php echo $_lang->getCode();?>">
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: this is the code of . app/design/frontend/[theme-directory]/template/page/switch/languages.phtml

Comment: What is the question? What did you try, and what errors occured / why did it not work?

Comment: i am trying to display Language Flags from skin/frontend/default/[theme-directory]/images/flags but it is going to skin/frontend/base/default/[theme-directory]/images/flags.so images are not coming.because images are in skin/frontend/default/[theme-directory]/images/flagspath

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can try with this

```
<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
<div class="language-switcher">
    <!--<span>Your Language: </span>-->
    <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getName()) ?>">
            <?php //echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getCode()) ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/flag/').$this->htmlEscape($_lang->getCode()).'.png' ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getName()) ?>" />
        </a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: don't forget to select this as answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens when you do not change the default skin directory from Magento backend.

System > Configuration > General > Design.

This should be changed to the your theme's skin folder. Also in case the if the default directory is changed but if magento does not find it it will take the base skin folder.

Comment: i have installed the theme grayscale and i have given my themes name in each and every field of  System > Configuration > General > Design >themes.

Comment: then make sure that these settings are being applied for the current store where you want the changes to reflect. Check if these settings have been changed in the scope of your store.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
<div class="language-switcher">
    <!--<span>Your Language: </span>-->
    <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getName()) ?>">
            <?php //echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getCode()) ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/flag/').$this->htmlEscape($_lang->getCode()).'.png' ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getName()) ?>" />
        </a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```